# Uploading a base64 image via Form upload

Tags: java, gwt

I have a web app that within it, it gets a base64 from the client side, omitting the details here is how the base64 is retrieved:

```
String source = e.getAttribute("src");
String base64 = source.substring(source.indexOf("base64,") + 7)
```

Now that the base64 string is retrieved, I need to upload it via Form upload. I'm not sure what is the correct approach to upload this as a File to my working backend.

The problem is not the backend, I have tested it to receive standard Form upload and it works fine. So the issue I face, is how to upload the base64 say to a backend endpoint `/blob/upload`

**Update:**

I'm thinking of using GWT Rpc to upload the base64 String but I am not sure if that is efficient for large files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you're uploading a Base64 String? It will probably get messy.

If there is no reason to do it that way, use the [com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html) widget on the client, and make a simple [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) on the backend to accept the files.

You can then use the [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html) library to grab the uploaded files and do with them as you please (See "The Simplest Case" section of that page for usage details. It's pretty easy to use).

Also, beware of large files. The default Tomcat POST size is 2 megabytes, I believe.